# combinations of all rows and cols from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

```
2   6
8   5
```

I want to yield the following list of lists:

```
[  [[2],[6,5]],
[[2],[6]],
[[2],[5]],
[[8],[6,5]],
[[8],[6]],
[[8],[5]],
[[6],[2,8]],
[[6],[8]],
[[6],[2]],
[[5],[2,8]],
[[5],[2]],
[[5],[8]],
[[6,5],[2,8]]  ]
```

I have written the following (which doesn't yield the expected results)

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
resList=[]
resListTmp=[]
resListTmp2=[]
dataframe = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\testData.xlsx",index_col=False,header=None)
for i in range(0, len(dataframe)+1):
    for j in range(0, len(dataframe.columns)):
        for k in range (0,len(dataframe)+1):
            for xVals in list(combinations(dataframe.iloc[k:i,j], i)):
                if list(xVals) not in resListTmp:
                    resListTmp.append(list(xVals))
        resListTmp2.append(resListTmp)
    resList.append(resListTmp2)                
print(resList)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this only a small start for a more general larger pattern?

Comment: You should clarify your question. In particular you should outline how the more general output is supposed to look like, for example parts of the expected output for a dataframe with 3 columns. This isn’t obvious at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly iterating through all possible combinations of rows and columns in your code. I have rewritten your code below, this one will extract the required elements from the dataframe and append them to the result list

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations, product

# Replace this line with your own data source
data = [[2, 6], [8, 5]]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_combinations(dataframe):
    res_list = []
    nrows, ncols = dataframe.shape
    
    for r in range(1, nrows+1):
        for c in range(1, ncols+1):
            row_combinations = list(combinations(range(nrows), r))
            col_combinations = list(combinations(range(ncols), c))
            
            for row_comb, col_comb in product(row_combinations, col_combinations):
                tmp = []
                for i in row_comb:
                    tmp.append([dataframe.iloc[i, j] for j in col_comb])
                if tmp not in res_list:
                    res_list.append(tmp)
    return res_list

result = get_combinations(dataframe)
print(result)
```

Comment: I got this result `[[[2]], [[6]], [[8]], [[5]], [[2, 6]], [[8, 5]], [[2], [8]], [[6], [5]], [[2, 6], [8, 5]]]` which is not exactly what i am looking for as output.